# Firebase Remote Config not updating on locale change

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have the below defined:

[image]

I first launch the app with the device's language (from Settings) set to English and it loads the lang-EN json.
If I go in the Settings of the device, change the language to French and restart the app, `.fetch()` will still return the lang-EN value. If I clear cache the app and restart it, it then loads the lang-FR value.

Doesn't `.fetch()` get ALL the remote config params and locally decide which to show the user? From the functionality i'm getting it seems that `.fetch()` only gets the parameter values only pertaining to the device at the moment of the call. Either that or there's a bug in the firebase code ... OR ... and i'm hoping this is the case, i'm doing something wrong.

This is how i'm initializing the singleton. Perhaps i'm missing something?

```
public void initialize(Context applicationContext) {
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
            .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(5 * 60 * 60)//5 hours
            .build();
    getConfig().setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings);
}
```

And yes, i have the latest version of the remote config sdk in the dependencies `19.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

`fetch()` is not enough.

To fetch parameter values from the Remote Config backend, call the `fetch()` method. Any values that you set in the backend are fetched and stored in the Remote Config object.
To make fetched parameter values available to your app, call the `activate()` method.

For cases where you want to fetch and activate values in one call, you can use a `fetchAndActivate()` request to fetch values from the Remote Config backend and make them available to the app:

```java
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    boolean updated = task.getResult();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Config params updated: " + updated);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch and activate succeeded",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch failed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                displayWelcomeMessage();
            }
        });
```

Because these updated parameter values affect the behavior and appearance of your app, you should activate the fetched values at a time that ensures a smooth experience for your user, such as the next time that the user opens your app